# What does 肩の凝る mean?

Tags: words

> 彼の聞く音楽といったら**肩の凝る**ものばかりだ。

The translation was:

> He always listens to serious music.

Comment: Did you look up these words in a dictionary? Do you understand why の is used here?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I couldn't understand what it meant in that sentence.

Comment: 肩が凝る would refers to how "fatiguing"  the music he listens to is. More specifically music of the elaborate, heavily structured kind that takes a lot of mental effort to fully appreciate, as opposed to simple and relaxing, "easy-listening" music that you turn on to distract yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/41611/meaning/m0u/:

> 肩(かた)が凝(こ)・る
>   ２　重圧を感じて気詰まりである。肩が張る。

TL: feel ill at ease, uncomfortable, feel constrained, unable to relax.

---

Examples from http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/12384/meaning/m0u/:

> あの人と話をしていると肩が凝る。
>   I feel uncomfortable when I am talking with him.
>
> 社長と話すといつも肩が凝る
>   I always feel ill at ease when I speak with the boss.
>
> もっと肩の凝らない話にしようよ
>   Let's switch to a lighter [less demanding] subject.

Answer (score 1):

肩{かた｝の凝｛こ｝る - stiffening of shoulder muscles

It's usually used in reference to sitting at a desk for long hours and your shoulders getting stiff, but in this sentence I think it's left to your own interpretation of what "shoulder-stiffening music" is.